# C#: Rounding up to 2 maximum decimal points for Double variables

Tags: c#, double, decimal

Is there any chance to format a double value after an operation to come up with only 2 decimal values?
Because i am making a weather report and i'm getting the average of weather data per 5 minutes and i want  to make it formal to have only 2 decimal places.

Which instead of having 10240.8999 i could have 10240.90.
Any thoughts or suggestion?

Comment: There are dozens of duplicates on this site already. And you're not really clear whether you want to _round_ or _format_ a number.

Comment: sorry about the confusion :" i am more referring to rounding up. ill change it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Round with 2 decimals and convert to string to force 2 decimals

```
string rounded = String.Format("{0:f2}", Math.Round(10240.8999, 2));
```

Gives `10240.90`

Comment: Rounding _and_ formatting seems a little redundant.

Comment: Not really if you want the `0` in the end

Comment: thanks bro i used this and got what i want :)

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, the way to do this is:

```
var rounded = Math.Round(valueToRound, 2);
```

for `decimal` variables:

```
var rounded = Decimal.Round(valueToRound, 2);
```